# How to get product category ID based on post?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to show certain images on product pages based on the category ID. How can I achieve it on the product page?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to get the terms of the current post for certain taxonomy. Then loop the found terms and check, if one of them has certain ID.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && $terms ) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if ( 123 === $term->term_id ) {
            echo '<img src="my-image.jpg">';
        }
    }
}
```

Another option could be to use [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) to check, if the current post has certain term in a more compact way.

```
if ( has_term( $term_or_slug_or_term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo '<img src="my-image.jpg">';
}
```